# Check if system has sound C#

Tags: c#, xna, audio

We are currently developing a game using XNA and we've stumbled upon a little sound problem.

When a system has no sound device plugged in (speakers, etc. -- when Win7 shows a red cross on the speaker icon) it crashes when trying to play/load the sound.

So, we would like to check if the system has the capacity of outputting sound. Is it possible in C#?

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure that it is actually crashing, and not simply throwing an unhandled exception?

In theory it should throw a `NoAudioHardwareException`.

Try doing something with audio (`SoundEffect.MasterVolume` comes to mind as a possibility, as it is a static method) and see if you can catch the exception. If you do catch an exception, simply do no further audio work.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will helps.........

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern long GetNumDevs();
private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    long I = 0;
    I = GetNumDevs();
    if (I > 0) {
        Interaction.MsgBox("Your system can play sound files.");
    } else {
        Interaction.MsgBox("Your system can not play sound files.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers without any explanation don't tend to be helpful at all.

Comment: I don't see a raw `GetNumDevs` in winmm.dll on my Windows 7 system. Did you mean [waveOutGetNumDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743860.aspx)? And do you really mean `CharSet.Ansi`?? That's almost always not the best choice, and AFAICS there are no strings here anyway.