# Ignore missing audio device in XNA

Tags: xna

When I try to run an XNA application on a windows 7 machine that has an audio device, but it doesn't have any speakers plugged in, I get the following error message:

> Could not find a suitable audio device.  Verify that a sound card is
>   installed, and check the driver properties to make sure it is not
>   disabled

Is there a way to catch this error an ignore it.  I don't really care if the player has any sound or not, the game should still run in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651106/165500): In theory it should throw a `NoAudioHardwareException`.

So try doing something with audio (`SoundEffect.MasterVolume` comes to mind as a possibility, as it is a static method) and see if you can catch the exception. If you do catch an exception, simply do no further audio work.